# Meaning of "passed yet"

Tags: word-meaning

> She could have passed yet for a human if not for the long, tapering
>   ears jutting from the hair,  pointed ears marking her race.

I can understand the whole sentence, in general.

*She looked human except for the ears, which made her noticeably different.*

Comment: It means along the lines of "she looked enough like a human that she could pass for being human, except for the ears that give away her race," however I'm not sure why the author chose to include "yet" there.

Comment: This is not a normal way of talking in modern English, FYI, it's characteristic of fiction taking place in fantasy worlds, medieval settings, that sort of thing. I think the modern way to say it is, "She could *even* have passed for human..."

Comment: This is from Warcraft war of the acients. The author's writing style so abnormal

Answer (score 1):

OP's context matches [item #6](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/yet) in the Macmillan Dictionary...

> **yet** - *used for introducing a word or idea that is surprising after what has just been mentioned*

...and could be replaced with something like *nevertheless* or *even so*. OP doesn't provide the preceding context, but it *should* include something matching *what has just been mentioned* above.

Note that this particular usage has little direct connection to "the passage of time". In this respect it's similar to ***still***, which is more common in current English (OP's example is deliberately somewhat "archaic").

Thus *I'm still in love* (archaically or poetically, *I am yet in love*) could either mean *I love my partner even after the passage of time* (the "literal" sense of *still/yet*) or the more metaphoric *I love her **despite** all the mean things she does/did to me* (those mean things having been previously mentioned).